# Using Ember Data to load data async from node sever

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express, ember-data

**My Model :**

```
App.Contacts = DS.Model.extend({
        name : DS.attr('string'),
        number : DS.attr('number')
    });
```

This is how i save a record :

```
        App.AddController = Ember.Controller.extend({
            actions : {
                addContact : function(){

                var post =  this.store.createRecord('Contacts',{
                        name :  this.get('name') ,
                        number : this.get('number')
                    });
                post.save();
                }
            }
        });
```

Acc to Ember's offical guide, this would send a `POST` request to `/Contacts` , so to handle it, i used this in nodejs/expressjs

```
        app.post('/contacts',function(req,res){
            posts.push( req.body);
            console.log(posts);
            res.send({status: 'OK'});
        });
```

Now i wish to retrieve it, into another template called `all` so i used :

```
                           App.AllRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
            model : function(){
            return this.store.find('Contacts');

            },
            setupController : function(controller,model){
                controller.set('contactList',model);
            }
        });
```

Acc to Emberjs guides, model hook supports promises out-of-the-box . so i assumed this should work.

**My template** :

```
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="all" >

        Hello
          <table>
          {{#each contact in contactList}}
            <tr>
            <td>{{contact.name}} </td>
            <td>{{contact.number}} </td>
            </tr>
            {{else}}
            <tr><td>No contacts yet </td> </tr>
          {{/each}}
          </table>

        </script>
```

**Question**

But the model returns nothing, i understand that `this.store.find('Contacts')` doesn't return a javascript array, but essentially and object , implimenting `Ember.Enumerable` 
But on the server side, the `posts` is an javascript array, therefore there might be an type mismatch between then. how to resolve this?

**EDIT**:
To avoid any confusions in client side Ember code , This works properly, so there is some problem with the round trip to server.

```
App.AllRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model : function(){
            return this.store.all('Contacts');

            },
        setupController : function(controller,model){
            controller.set('contactList',model);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a jsfiddle, it be nice. I'm not sure whether contactList is defined or not and whether the alias for that controller is actually defined. So based on what I see, I think the problem is you're iterating over a controller that does not have the model properly defined.

I'd suggest trying to do:

```
{{#each}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{contact.name}} </td>
      <td>{{contact.number}} </td>
    </tr>
    {{else}}
    <tr><td>No contacts yet </td> </tr>
{{/each}}
```

If you really want to use the contactList controller, then you need to make sure that the App.AllController "needs" the contactListController.

```
App.ContactListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({}) // needs to be an array controller
App.AddController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   needs: ["contactList"], // controller's used within this controller
contactList: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.contactList"), // needed to iterate over the model how you're doing it.
```

Both of these solutions should work assuming your data is actually loaded in Ember Data. You might want to check the "data" tab on the ember-data console. If you don't have that browser extension installed, do it. It's incredibly useful.

If all else fails, try logging to verify expected values using {{log contactList}}

Good luck

Comment: None of them works, also i updated the question to make it clear that ember is not the culprit and server is not returning data is expected format.